# XML only displays last item in array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xml, parsing

Here is an example of the XML file I have. I have everything parsed, but can't get the array to display all items.

```
<dish>
    <title> Pancakes </title>
    <calories> 350 calories </calories>
    <ingredients>
        <item>ingredient 1</item>
        <item>ingredient 2</item>
        <item>ingredient 3</item>
    </ingredients>
</dish>
```

I have a struct of Recipes and a struct of Ingredients. The ingredients only has a variable of "item" in it. I've removed some of the recipe code to include the ingredients portion of the parsing code, since everything else works and prints.

```
struct Ingredients {
   var item = ""
}

var tableViewDataSource = [Recipes]()
var tableViewIngSource = [Ingredients]()

 func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    thisName = elementName

    // elementName == "recipe" code

    if elementName == "ingredients" {
        var recipeItem = ""
    }

}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if data.count != 0 {
        switch thisName
        {
        case "title": recipeTitle = data
        case "calories": recipeCalories = data
        case "ingredients": recipeIngredients = data
        case "item": recipeItem = data
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "dish" {
        var recipe = Recipes()
        recipe.title = recipeTitle
        recipe.duration = recipeDuration
        recipe.calories = recipeCalories
        recipe.ingredients = recipeIngredients
        recipe.description = recipeDescription

        //print(recipe)
        tableViewDataSource.append(recipe)

    }

    if elementName == "ingredients" {
        var ingredients = Ingredients()
        ingredients.item = recipeItem

        for item in tableViewIngSource {
            print(item)
        }

        print(ingredients)
        print(tableViewIngSource.count)
        tableViewIngSource.append(ingredients)
    }
}
```

This is the output. It results in the last two print statement outputs, the for loop does not print anything

```
Ingredients(item: "ingredient 3")
0
```

From what I've seen, a custom XML parser needs to be used. I've looked into SWXMLHash, but it seems the XML code needs to be in the swift file

Comment: Where is the `recipe` element that you are referencing in your code? Does your XML have many `dish` elements? Could you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a good bit of reorganizing to properly parse the XML data.

The following is more like what you want to have:

Your Recipe structure (Note it is Recipe, not Recipes since it represents one recipe):

```
struct Recipe {
    let title: String
    let calories: String
    let ingredients: [String]
}
```

Your parsing code:

```
var currentText: String?
var recipeTitle: String?
var recipeCalories: String?
var recipeIngredients: [String]?

var tableViewDataSource = [Recipe]()

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    switch elementName {
    case "dish":
        recipeTitle = nil
        recipeCalories = nil
        recipeIngredients = nil
    case "ingredients":
        recipeIngredients = []
    case "title", "calories", "item":
        currentText = ""
    default:
        break
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    switch elementName {
    case "dish":
        if let recipeTitle = recipeTitle, let recipeCalories = recipeCalories, let recipeIngredients = recipeIngredients {
            let recipe = Recipe(title: recipeTitle, calories: recipeCalories, ingredients: recipeIngredients)
            tableViewDataSource.append(recipe)
        }
        recipeTitle = nil
        recipeCalories = nil
        recipeIngredients = nil
    case "title":
        recipeTitle = currentText?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        currentText = nil
    case "calories":
        recipeCalories = currentText?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        currentText = nil
    case "item":
        if let currentText = currentText {
            recipeIngredients?.append(currentText.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines))
        }
        currentText = nil
    default:
        break
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    currentText?.append(string)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm working with the code Thursday so I'll update with my progress

Comment: It definitely helped, but was conflicting in other parts of my tableview code which needed to display it. Nonetheless, I was able to find a workaround. Thanks again!

Comment: How did it conflict? The code I posted has nothing to do with a table view.

Comment: The code itself was fine. I needed to take the array and display it in a textarea, and still had complications with that

Comment: If this answer solved your parsing issue, you should indicate this by accepting the answer.